# When the TableView is clicked, how can I match the id with the id on the detail page and pull the data?

Tags: swift, api, didselectrowatindexpath, detailsview, detailview

When the TableView is clicked, how can I match the id with the id on the detail page and pull the data?

I am making an application in the form of 2 pages https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon There will be Main and Detail pages using the Api.
I created a table with pictures and names on the main page. But I am stuck on the detail page and cannot proceed.

I am trying to create a detail page where I need to fill in the DidSelect section. When I click on any cell in the tableview it is. I want the picture and detailed features of the pokemon in the cell to appear.

I want to show on the detail page
-Name
-Image
-Stat
-Abilities
-Height

**MainViewController**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var pokemons: [GetPokemonsResponse.Pokemon] = []
    private var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PokemonTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        
        activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        activityIndicatorView.center = tableView.center
        tableView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        getPokemons()
    }
    
    private func getPokemons() {
            PokeAPIService.shared.getPokemons { response in
                self.pokemons = response.results
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }


}
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokemons.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath) as? PokemonTableViewCell {
            let pokemon = pokemons[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameLabel.text = pokemons[indexPath.row].name
            cell.loadImage(from: PokeAPIService.shared.getPokemonSprites(id: pokemon.pokemonID))
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
  
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var abilitiesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statsLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    }

}
```

**PokeApiService**

```
import Foundation

class PokeAPIService {
    
    static let shared = PokeAPIService()
    let limitNumber = 40
    
    func getPokemons(completion: @escaping (GetPokemonsResponse) -> Void) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=\(limitNumber)") else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetPokemonsResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(response)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    
    func getPokemon(by id: String, completion: @escaping (GetPokemonResponse) -> Void) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/\(id)/") else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetPokemonResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(response)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    
    func getPokemonSprites(id: String) -> URL? {
           URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/\(id).png")
       }
       
       func getPokemonOfficialArtwork(id: String) -> URL?{
           URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/\(id).png")
       }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct GetPokemonResponse: Codable {
    let abilities: [Ability]?
    let baseExperience: Int?
    let forms: [Species]?
    let gameIndices: [GameIndex]?
    let height: Int?
    let heldItems: [JSONAny]?
    let id: Int?
    let isDefault: Bool?
    let locationAreaEncounters: String?
    let moves: [Move]?
    let name: String?
    let order: Int?
    let pastTypes: [JSONAny]?
    let species: Species?
    let sprites: Sprites?
    let stats: [Stat]?
    let types: [TypeElement]?
    let weight: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case abilities
        case baseExperience = "base_experience"
        case forms
        case gameIndices = "game_indices"
        case height
        case heldItems = "held_items"
        case id
        case isDefault = "is_default"
        case locationAreaEncounters = "location_area_encounters"
        case moves, name, order
        case pastTypes = "past_types"
        case species, sprites, stats, types, weight
    }
}
// MARK: - Ability
struct Ability: Codable {
    let ability: Species?
    let isHidden: Bool?
    let slot: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ability
        case isHidden = "is_hidden"
        case slot
    }
}

// MARK: - Species
struct Species: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let url: String?
}
// MARK: - Stat
struct Stat: Codable {
    let baseStat, effort: Int?
    let stat: Species?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case baseStat = "base_stat"
        case effort, stat
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make this a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! Not all of your variables are relevant to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create some variables in your `detailViewController`. Then in your tableviews didselect method you can create an object of `detaileViewController. Then pass the required information to the variables using the detailsVC object. Here is a sample code for your problem. Hope you will understand,

**DidiSelectRowAt method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let pokemon = pokemons[indexPath.row]
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
    
    detailViewController.pokemonName = pokemonDetails.name
    detailViewController.detailsImageUrl = // provide the image url or which response came from the api call
    detailViewController.stats = pokemonDetails.stats.effort // use your required stat
    detailViewController.abilities = pokemonDetails.abilities.slots
    detailViewController.pokemonHeight = pokemonDetails.height
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
            
    }
```

**detailViewController**

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let pokemonName: String?
    let detailImageUrl: String?
    let pokemonHeight: Int?
    let abilities: Int?
    let stats: Int?
  
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var abilitiesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statsLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
    }

}
```

In DetailsViewControllers ViewDidLoad you should use the variables to populate your outlets

Comment: This will not work.